# Creating a HashSet from a column of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a built in way (LINQ maybe?) of taking all the row values from a specific column from a DataTable and creating a HashSet from it? The column is also of type String.

I could obviously do this in a loop but I was wondering if there is another way?

I'm using .net 3.5 btw.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Well DataTable.Columns[0] will give you a list right. You can use Linq extension on that and do what ever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HashSet<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>)`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx

Answer (score 2):

try this, but not sure of how to copy the array values for hashtable values without loop.

```
string[] strArray = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("MyContent")).ToArray<string>();
```

Then copy things to hashtable values (loop is one way).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes it did, I also used the HashSet<T>.Union method to merge the results with my existing hashset.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal using LINQ:

```
    IEnumerable<string> values = 
        dataTable
        .Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select(row => row["ColumnName"])
        .Cast<string>();

    HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
}
```

then call

```
HashSet<string> values = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("Columnname")).ToHashSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a project and switched it to 3.5.
There's a simple one liner to accomplish this (thank goodness for LINQ).
Hopefully this helps anyone in the future who takes a look at this.

```
HashSet<string> yourHashSet = new HashSet<string>(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("YourColumn")))
```

Note: this solution is for .NET Framework 3.5+